# How can I hide element html depends role in angular

Tags: html, angular, authentication, frontend, nestjs

I have 4 kind of profiles (role)

- adminstrator
- Super Admin
- Admin
- User

every profile has it's own pages of creation or displaying but with little difference, I guess it's waste of time when I create component just to add one fields, so is there any solution how to hide/show element html depends role ?

Comment: Lookup `RoleGuard`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an enum of roles and use it in your html via [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) or [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet).